# Trouble getting dict.setdefault to work with tuple argument

Tags: python, dictionary, setdefault

```
#!/bin/python

import logging
import sys

logging.basicConfig(
    format="%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(name)s - %(message)s",
    level=logging.INFO,
    datefmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
    stream=sys.stdout,
)
logger = logging.getLogger("mylogger")

cache = {}

# Relevant stuff begins here.
def cacheDecorator(func):

    """
    Goal is to decorate a function so that successive calls to it with the same
    arguments return the cached value, rather than invoking the function again
    unnecessarily.
    :param func:
    :return:  cached value when possible
    """

    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        # This works
        global cache

        if args in cache:
            return cache.get(args)
        else:
            retVal = func(*args, **kwargs)
            cache[args] = retVal
            return  retVal

    def wrapper2(*args, **kwargs):
        # This doesn't work - it always invokes func even on successive
        # calls with the same input arguments passed to f1.
        global cache
        return cache.setdefault(args,func(*args, **kwargs) )

    #return wrapper # Causes f1 to be executed only once, as desired
    return wrapper2 # Causes f1 to be executed again even with same arguments. Why??

@cacheDecorator
def f1 (a, b, c, /):
    logger.info('Inside f1')
    result = a * b * c
    return result

logger.info (f'Result from executing f1(1,2,3) = {f1(1,2,3)}')
logger.info (f'Result from executing f1(1,2,3) again = {f1(1,2,3)}')

sys.exit(0)
```

I'm trying to write a decorator in Python that will cache the results of a function. When my `cacheDecorator` function returns `wrapper`, it does not make a second call to `f1`, but when `cacheDecorator` returns `wrapper2` instead, which attempts to make use of the dictionary's `setdefault` method, it `wrapper2` always invokes the func `f1`, and I don't understand why.

Comment: [functools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html) has a bunch of them, why not using stdlib?

Comment: No magic here, function calls fully evaluate all their function arguments and `dict.setdefault` is no exception there. This is simply not a good use-case for `dict.setdefault`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions and help!

Answer (score 1):

`return cache.setdefault(args, func(*args, **kwargs))` is equivalent to:

```
result = func(*args, **kwargs)
return cache.setdefault(args, result)
```

In other words, `func` gets called before `cache.setdefault`. As wim said in their comment: "This is simply not a good use-case for `dict.setdefault`".

A second problem you have is that your `cacheDecorator` is not reusable, because it uses a single global `cache` for all cached functions.

A third problem is that your cache key is based on `*args` but you also accept `**kwargs`. This means that `my_cached_function(10, 20, foo=True)` and `my_cached_function(10, 20, bar='hello')` both share a cache key, and which one is used is based on which one is called first!

Here is how you can modify your decorator to address these changes: (I left out everything that stays the same)

```
import functools

# cache = {}   # moved to inside the decorator

def cacheDecorator(func):
    cache = {}  # one cache per function

    @functools.wraps(func)  # improve debugging by telling Python wrapper() wraps func()
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        # very crude way to get a cache key
        # using inspect.signature you could make f(1) equivalent to f(a=1) if the first argument to f was named a.
        cache_key = (args, tuple(kwargs.items())
        if cache_key in cache:
            return cache.get(cache_key)
        else:
            ret_val = func(*args, **kwargs)
            cache[cache_key] = ret_val
            return ret_val

    return wrapper
```

Comment: One thing I didn't address: you didn't need `global cache` and here you don't need `nonlocal cache` because you never assign to `cache` inside the wrapper functions, you only mutate it.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions and help!